# Как сохранить изменения в Openshift?

Tags: git, openshift

Запушил сайт на Openshift (бесплатный). Всё работает. Загрузил картинки в галерею через админку. Если теперь сделать бекап или git clone или git pull, то получишь только то что было изначально в репозитории. Без изменений на продакшене. Как сделать коммит в тот репозиторий который хранится на Openshift, чтобы потом сделать git pull себе на комп всех изменений которые внесли пользователи через админку? Может я неправильно понимаю процесс и на Openshift можно только пушить, а все пользовательские файлы должны храниться на отдельном сервере?

Comment: опеншифт открыли?

Comment: @Sergey к сожалению, не понимаю вашего вопроса.

Comment: Там была регистрация закрыта из-за дефицита ресурсов. Обещали письмо написать, когда откроют. Но так и не написали сволочи.

Comment: @Sergey не в курсе, я зарегистрировался больше года назад, просто только сейчас время появилось поковырять (:

Comment: Другого решения не нашел, только [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406879/uploaded-files-getting-deleted-while-redeploying-in-openshift-server).